# select customer with the highest total orders per region, alongside both totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
SaleID    Region      Customer        OrderAmt
1         North       Keesha          10
2         West        Mary            10
3         North       Winston         10
4         North       John            10
5         North       Keesha          10
6         West        John            10
7         West        Mary            10
8         South       John            10
```

Using SQL Server 2012, what is the best way to select each region's highest-ordering customer, alongside the totals for the customer and for the region, i.e.:

```
Region    Customer    CustAmt   RegAmt
North     Keesha      20        40
West      Mary        20        30
South     John        10        10
```

Although multiple regions may contain the same names, we want `CustAmt` to be the total for that name only within each region, not across regions (i.e., in last line, John's total in South region is 10, not 30).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Awww, harsh! Believe me, I did hours of research, including checking for similar answers here and elsewhere. But despite all that I didn't get very close to a solution, so rather than spill ink on what didn't work, was trying to keep the post as short and clear as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT Region, Customer
        , sum(OrderAmt) AS CustAmt
        , sum(sum(OrderAmt)) OVER (PARTITION BY Region) AS RegAmt
        , row_number()  OVER (PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY sum(OrderAmt) DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY Region, Customer
   )
SELECT Region, Customer, CustAmt, RegAmt
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Or, the same with a subquery:

```
SELECT Region, Customer, CustAmt, RegAmt
FROM  (
   SELECT Region, Customer
        , sum(OrderAmt) AS CustAmt
        , sum(sum(OrderAmt)) OVER (PARTITION BY Region) AS RegAmt
        , row_number()  OVER (PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY sum(OrderAmt) DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY Region, Customer
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

The key features are window functions over an aggregate, so we only need a *single* CTE / subquery.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7861c/4)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I neglected to say in the question, and may not have been apparent from small sample dataset, that I also wanted to order the results by RegAmt DESC. But easy enough to add to these, even for a noob.

Answer (score 1):

In one select:

```
select top 1 with ties
    Region   , 
    Customer ,
    CustAmt  =  sum(OrderAmt),
    RegAmt   =  sum(sum(OrderAmt)) over (partition by Region)   
from
    your_table
group by    
    Region, 
    Customer
order by 
    row_number() over(partition by Region order by sum(OrderAmt) desc);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea4fc/2)**

Comment: Thanks! I neglected to say in the question, and may not have been apparent from small sample dataset, that I also wanted to order the results by RegAmt DESC. This worked, but as a noob I don't understand it as well as Erwin Brandstetter's answers and adding the extra sort would require more thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `CTE`s and window functions:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        CustAmt = SUM(OrderAmt) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Region),
        RegAmt  = SUM(OrderAmt) OVER(PARTITION BY Region)
    FROM Sales
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY CustAmt DESC)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    Region, Customer, CustAmt, RegAmt
FROM CteFinal WHERE rn = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf0b8/1/0)